# Hydrogen successfully installed but can't execute on Atom

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, atom-editor, hydrogen

I am having trouble with executing codes with `Hydrogen`. I have tried #1538 but had no luck. I am trying to setup Atom on my new Mac hence running into this issue.

1. Download Atom from https://atom.io
2. Dragged and dropped the file to `Applications`
3. Install all the shell commands : `Atom-> Install Shell commands`
4. On terminal :

```
python3 -m venv new_env
source new_env/bin/activate 
python3 -m pip install ipykernel
python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name new_env
```

5. Install `Hydrogen`
6. When I try to execute  for example `import numpy` it gives the following error on the side after it prompts to select the virtual env - `new_env` :

```
new_env

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
```

**Versions:**

- Python 3.10.2
- macOS Monterey
- Atom 1.59
- Hydrogen 2.16.3

**Additional details:**

```
{
  "kernelspecs": {
    "new_env": {
      "resource_dir": "/Users/shanaka/Library/Jupyter/kernels/new_env",
      "spec": {
        "argv": [
          "/Users/shanaka/Python/new_env/bin/python3",
          "-m",
          "ipykernel_launcher",
          "-f",
          "{connection_file}"
        ],
        "env": {},
        "display_name": "new_env",
        "language": "python",
        "interrupt_mode": "signal",
        "metadata": {
          "debugger": true
        }
      }
    },
    "python3": {
      "resource_dir": "/Users/shanaka/Python/new_env/share/jupyter/kernels/python3",
      "spec": {
        "argv": [
          "python",
          "-m",
          "ipykernel_launcher",
          "-f",
          "{connection_file}"
        ],
        "env": {},
        "display_name": "Python 3 (ipykernel)",
        "language": "python",
        "interrupt_mode": "signal",
        "metadata": {
          "debugger": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you installed hydrogen in the same venv?

Comment: No don't think so. Is that necessary? I just installed Hydrogen from Atom->preference->Install->Hydrogen. When I execute a line, it does pop up with the environment names.